Cement basement floor: demolish and redo, or cover with more cement?
 My basement floor is uneven, crumbling, and cracking. Would it be better to demolish and redo, or patch somehow.

The best answer would depend on what your intentions for the basement are.  Just a workshop and storage area, or a finished man cave?  Include that info in your question.

Personally, I wouldn't demolish.  I'd probably just skim epoxy over the whole floor (obvs clean it all up first!).
